# On hold should be timed

Tags: discussion, on-hold

I asked a question on Network Engineering. Question has been put on-hold after less than 10 minutes after creation.
While I do not contest the utility of the "on-hold" flag I suggest allowing some time (hours or days) before flagging the question. If Stack-Exchange aspires to be a real open to discussion and open to opinions platform it should give an equal  chance to both parties.
Flagging a question shortly after creation kills all chances to be answered by a late reader and demoralizes the asking person who expects something positive, constructive not a door-slam in face.
There is a hunt-for-questions and a competition for answering-question-rewards on this site. My personal feeling is the first arrived, if it doesn't know the answer and have enough privileges will flash the question "on-hold" closing all later attempts to answer it. It is detrimental for everyone and for the knowledge base.

Comment: You're free to disagree but there is no need to become rude and offensive. Please [be nice](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice)

Comment: Stackexchange websites are not discussion forums.  If we are discussing if a question should be closed then we are breaking an established guideline

Comment: *Stack-Exchange aspires to be a real open to discussion and open to opinions platform* well, it doesn't, so I guess there's no real problem here.

Answer (score 16):

I feel the need to correct this idea immediately:

> If Stack-Exchange aspires to be a real open to discussion and open to opinions platform

Stack Exchange aspires to be discussion free and closed to opinion based questions - we value questions where *objective* answers are possible and questions that ask for opinions kinda go against that.

We do not want discussions either. We focus on questions and their answers. Not discussions.

---

Perhaps the above will help you understand why on-hold *should not* be time limited.